# rsyslog forwarder seems not not work

Tags: logstash, syslog, rsyslog

I would like to send rsyslog message to my ELK stack but it does not work
rsyslog conf

```
*.* @@127.0.0.1:10514
local6.*    /tmp/grenard.log
&~
```

logstash conf

```
input {
        syslog {                 
           port => 10514
           type => "syslog"
        }
        stdin {}
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```

logstash listens really on 10514 (telnet localhost 10514
)(test with a localhost telent 10514 and I can see it in my stdout

> root@VM-GUILLAUME /etc/logstash/conf.d #  /opt/logstash/bin/logstash
>   -f /etc/logstash/conf.d Settings: Default filter workers: 4 Logstash startup completed {
>              "message" => "bonjour\r\n",
>             "@version" => "1",
>           "@timestamp" => "2016-03-01T10:55:41.488Z",
>                 "type" => "syslog",
>                 "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
>                 "tags" => [
>           [0] "_grokparsefailure_sysloginput"

Moreover, the logfile is fulfilled so I know my rsyslog conf is OK

```
logger -t apache -i -p local6.info $(date)
```

the log file

> Mar  1 12:06:04 localhost apache[13700]: mar. mars 1 12:06:04 CET 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to tcp (@@). using udp (@) problem solved. Here my rsyslod.d/grenard.conf

```
*.* @127.0.0.1:10514
local6.*        /tmp/grenard.log

&~
```